# Geoserver Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, apache

I have web client on Apache and WFS service on Geoserver, both on same computer!
Web client is (Apache) running on port 89, and Geoserver is running on 8181 port!
I do following settings in Apache config file:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from `localhost
</Proxy>



 ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8181/geoserver/web
    ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8181/geoserver/web`
<Location /geoserver>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

When I try to run client page I am getting error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:8181/geoserver/wfs`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `'http://localhost:89'` is therefore not allowed access.

Are there any settings that I need to do in Geoserver to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the fact you didn't included the line

> OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

into your Apache server proxy.cgi file.

See [Configuring GeoServer Proxy for Public and Remote Data Access](http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/21-intermediate-geoserver-tutorials/38-configuring-geoserver-proxy-for-public-and-remote-data-access.html) and you'll discover that your ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives aren't properly configured, also (you didn't need the /web suffix).

Comment: I edit apache config file with this:ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8181/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8181/geoserver. And put following line in code  OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=". After all this when I try to search WFS I am getting this message:XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:89/qgis-web-client-master/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8181%2Fgeoserver%2Fwfs".

Comment: What did you see when you try to access localhost:89/geoserver/wms into your browser?

Comment: This is what I can see:
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameterValue" locator="request">
<ows:ExceptionText>
Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.monitor.MonitorServletRequest@1be51a
</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>

Comment: From your log I can see GeoServer looks for the owsAll.xsd file in a GeoServer working on the (default) 8080 port. Your Proxy settings are for 8081 port. Now, please, check your tomcat/conf/server.xml Make sure you have set the 8091 port instead the default 8080. You must have <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout=..........

Comment: I presume Apache Tomcat is your servlet container...

Comment: It's the same thing. I change this port but nothing happen!

Comment: Have you restarted the Tomcat server or, better, the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your proxy syntax

```
ProxyPass /geoserver/ http://localhost:8181/geoserver/
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver/ http://localhost:8181/geoserver/
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete comment in httpd.conf line:
mod_proxy.so 
and
mod_proxy_http.so

This modules operate proxy.
And of course restart Apache.